# In MPI how to get communicator when using several executables?

Tags: fortran, mpi, distributed

In MPI we work with multiple process that do not share anything but communicate with recv/send operations. The recv/send operations are done with respect to a communicator which can be the whole set of processors or a subset of them. The basic commands are:

```
call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr )
call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank, ierr )
```

with **MPI_COMM_WORLD** the communicator associated to the set of all processors. One interesting feature of MPI is that we can run several executables together with the command:

```
mpirun -n 3 prog1 : -n 2 prog2
```

with 3 nodes assigned to the first executable and 2 to the second. However for practical work, one would like to have a communicator associated to prog1 or prog2. Is there a way to get thi directly without using the command **MPI_COMM_SPLIT**?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such predefined communicator specified by the standard.

The great philosopher Jagger once said “you can’t always get what you want” and your best bet here is indeed to use `MPI_Comm_split()` and the value of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`'s `MPI_APPNUM` attribute as the `color` argument.

From the MPI 3.1 standard chapter 10.5.3

> 10.5.3 MPI_APPNUM
>
> There is a predefined attribute MPI_APPNUM of MPI_COMM_WORLD. In Fortran, the attribute is an integer value. In C,
>   the attribute is a pointer to an integer value. If a process was
>   spawned with MPI_COMM_SPAWN_MULTIPLE, MPI_APPNUM is the command number
>   that generated the current process. Numbering starts from zero. If a
>   process was spawned with MPI_COMM_SPAWN, it will have MPI_APPNUM equal
>   to zero. Additionally, if the process was not started by a spawn call,
>   but by an implementation specific startup mechanism that can handle
>   multiple process specifications, MPI_APPNUM should be set to the number
>   of the corresponding process specification. In particular, if it is
>   started with
>
> mpiexec spec0 [: spec1 : spec2 : ...]
>
> MPI_APPNUM should be set to the number of the corresponding specification.
>
> If an application was not spawned with MPI_COMM_SPAWN or
>   MPI_COMM_SPAWN_MULTIPLE, and MPI_APPNUM does not make sense in the
>   context of the implementation-specific startup mechanism, MPI_APPNUM is
>   not set.
>
> MPI implementations may optionally provide a mechanism to
>   override the value of MPI_APPNUM through the info argument. MPI
>   reserves the following key for all SPAWN calls.
>
> appnum Value contains
>   an integer that overrides the default value for MPI_APPNUM in the
>   child.
>
> Rationale.
>
> When a single application is started, it is able to
>   figure out how many processes there are by looking at the size of
>   MPI_COMM_WORLD. An application consisting of multiple SPMD
>   sub-applications has no way to find out how many sub-applications there
>   are and to which sub-application the process belongs. While there are
>   ways to figure it out in special cases, there is no general mechanism.
>   MPI_APPNUM provides such a general mechanism. (End of rationale.)

Comment: The question is "without using the command MPI_COMM_SPLIT", so this doesn't really answer what the poster is asking. Quite why they want to avoid the extremely useful MPI_COMM_SPLIT routine is another question ...

Comment: Yep, I misread the question ... unless the OP really meant to ask how to simply get the color to be passed to `MPI_Comm_split()` (which is not really expensive at the beginning of the program) ...

Comment: This indeed answers my question. I have to use MPI_COMM_SPLIT. I thought it would have made sense to have such a communicator directly, but that ain't so then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody interested in splitting the MPI_COMM_WORLD, I wrote a small utility library (one header). It splits the communicator into local communicators and establishes intercommunicators between them. It takes care of many of the technicalities:

You can find the header at: https://github.com/cfd-go/MPI_MPMD

It also gives the same syntax for running multiple programs at once, and spawning programs. If you have any questions or ideas to extend this, open an issue at github.

For example, in your first program you do:

```cpp
MPMDHelper MPMD;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPMD.Init(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "programA");
MPMD.local //<-- this is your local Comm.
```

In the other program you do:

```cpp
MPMDHelper MPMD;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPMD.Init(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "programB");
MPMD.local //<-- this is your local Comm.
MPMD["programA"].local //<-- intercommunicator for communication with programA
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to use the client-server mechanism that is described by MPI standard (the chapter on this can be found [here](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node242.htm#Node242)). The idea there is that you compile two independent MPI applications. One of them eventually becomes a server and opens a port for connections. Then the other one is the client that has to connect to that port. The code will look something like this:

Server:

```
program server

    use mpi_f08
    implicit none

    integer :: error
    type(MPI_Comm) :: intercomm

    real, dimension(5) :: data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    character(len=MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME) :: port_name

    ! Normal MPI initialization
    call MPI_Init(error)

    ! Here we open a port for incoming connections
    call MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name, error)
    ! Copy it in order to pass the address to a client
    print*, "PORT NAME:", port_name
    ! Accept the incoming connection creating the intercommunicator
    call MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, intercomm, error)
    ! Send test data
    call MPI_Send(data, 5, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, intercomm)
    print*, "DATA SENT"
    ! Close connection
    call MPI_Comm_disconnect(intercomm, error)

    call MPI_Finalize(error)

end program server
```

Client:

```
program client
    use mpi_f08
    implicit none

    integer :: error
    type(MPI_Comm) :: intercomm
    type(MPI_Status) :: status

    real, dimension(5) :: data = [0,0,0,0,0]
    character(len=MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME) :: port_name

    call MPI_Init(error)

    ! Here we copy the port name obtained from the server
    print*, "Type in port name"
    read(*,*) port_name

    ! Establish a connection creating the intercommunicator
    call MPI_Comm_connect(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, intercomm, error)
    ! Receive test data
    call MPI_Recv(data, 5, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, intercomm, status, error)
    print*, "DATA RECEIVED", data
    ! Close connection
    call MPI_Comm_disconnect(intercomm, error)

    call MPI_Finalize(error)

end program client
```

In a real program you may find some other way of transferring the information about the port address to the client (e.g. name publishing or file system transfer). Then you can just run your code like this:

```
mpirun -n <N1> server &
mpirun -n <N2> client
```

Few things to note about this approach. If you create only one intercommunicator - you will have only one MPI task from each side communicating to the partner code. If you need to send a lot of data - you may want to consider creating multiple intercommunicators. In addition, the implementation of this part of the MPI standard may be somewhat finicky (for instance in Open MPI 2.x there was a bug preventing its usage completely).

Comment: If you want to follow that road, starting the server and then `MPI_Comm_spawn()` the client is imho much less convoluted, and you will avoid side effects such as ending with MPI tasks from two distinct mpirun invocation pinned to the same core (and hence time sharing).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet doesn't it still have the potential to oversubscribe the system? In addition, this will probably require one to add more command-line options (at least one?). With a client-server approach one can also avoid putting MPI tasks of distinct applications on the same core via a number of ways. If we're talking about a cluster - then it should be possible already at the level of the queue system. On a single node/machine - one can use machine files. BTW, I think your comment addresses the question as well - you may want to add it as an additional option in your answer.

Comment: It has the potential to oversubscribe the system. That being said, if you care not to start more MPI tasks than available slots, then that should not happen. If you submit two jobs in a RM, then they might not start together and one will have to wait for the other which inefficient at the very least. I still believe one job with one mpirun MPMD and `MPI_Comm_split()` is the best fit here.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I was more thinking along the line of starting both MPI applications within a single job. But yes, I do believe that MPI_Comm_split is a better way of doing that, especially since not every HPC facility even allows dynamic MPI task spawning (which also blocks the client-server interaction).